# Excel: format first/last name to "lastname.firstinitial" format

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have exported a CSV of a list of employees.  In cell A1 (the name format is the complete first name, space and then the complete last name).  How do I make a cell with complete last, underscore then first letter of the first name) example: A1, reads (John Smith) can cell B1 be formatted to show Smith_J)

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to make two columns, Column A for the first name and Column B for the last name.

**Your formula would then be** `=B1&"_"&LEFT(A1,1)`

This formula basically grabs the last name (B1), adds an underscore `&"_"&`, then grabs the first character of the first name column `LEFT(A1,1)`.

---

**If you can't divide the first name / last name column, your formula would be more complicated:**

`=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,256)&"_"&LEFT(A1,1)`

This formula gets all the characters that appear after the first space character `=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,256)`, adds an underscore `&"_"&`, then grabs the first character of the string (first initial) `LEFT(A1,1)`

Comment: A good answer, but I'm not enamoured of the use of `256` to include the rest of the string. A matter of style, of course, but I prefer `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))&"_"&LEFT(A1,1)`.

Comment: My mind can only go so complex before it shuts off. Ha! Much more elegant though. +1